# How do I enable power management on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, laptop, power-management, acpi

I have Ubuntu Server 11.04 installed on an old noisy laptop. Its only purpose is to run subversion and I commit code quite rarely, but the laptop should work all the time.

So I would like to know how to turn on power management features for Ubuntu Server to enable automatic cpu scaling (reduce noise and heat) and make system power off display.

Comment: What CPU is there and does it support CPU scaling? You could try `powertop` from the repositories to help you figure that out. As for the display, it should turn of by itself, it does even when installing of an alternate CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the manual method (using shell scripts) but I do not know of it.
This software seems to be able to do the job (http://www.ubuntugeek.com/micromiser-power-saving-software-for-ubuntu-laptopsdesktopsservers.html), but it has been renamed (it seems) to Granola.

So, use Granola from here: `http://grano.la/support/linux_install.php?download&os=linux`. Just download the installer.bash file and follow the instructions on the same web page to download and install granola.

> NOTE: This URL is no longer valid, however it was left alone for historical reasons by moderators.

Comment: Hi rigved, the provided link is pointing to a parked domain.